Best way to report indirect effects in a complex Structural Equation Model (SEM) with a large number of variables and paths
I am fitting a complex structural equation model (SEM) with 4 latent and 2 observed variables (15 direct and 36 indirect effects). Importantly, in this model, some indirect effects from a given predictor to a given outcome are positive and some are negative (e.g., total effect = 5, but indirect effect 1 = 50, indirect effect 2 = -40, and indirect effect 3 = -5).
To make my analysis easier to understand, I thought about plotting the indirect effects of interest so that the reader could see the main conclusions at a glance.
I have considered several ways of doing this, all of which have advantages and disadvantages, and I cannot decide which is the most appropriate:

Plot the raw indirect effects with the total effect. Pros: It reports all raw results. Cons: In the case of suppression effects, it may be difficult to understand how much the most important indirect pathways contribute to the total effect.
Plot the percentage of a given effect in the total effect. Advantages: Allows the reader to understand the contribution of each indirect effect to the total effect. Disadvantages: Some percentages may be greater than 100 due to suppression effects. This was already mentioned here.
Solution two, but using the absolute total effect. In this solution, I would calculate the absolute total effect by summing the absolute value of the direct and indirect effects. Advantages: I can show the contribution of each mediation to the absolute total effect, with the direction of that mediation. Disadvantages: I sense disadvantages, but I cannot put my finger on them. Hence the question.

Each solution answers a different question, with advantages and disadvantages. I have come to mixed conclusions on my own, and definitely need an outside view on what you think is the most important information to convey to the reader in the main text (other interesting solutions may still find their way into the appendix).

EDIT: This question was also asked in the Lavaan forum.
